# How to format values in an interactive grid so every colon will be replaced with a newline for display purposes in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, formatting, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Oracle APEX 5.0.3

Hi,

I was wondering what would be the most efficient way to alter the way an Oracle APEX interactive report displays its sql return values. For example say a report returns a value of type VARCHAR that contains a list of values seperated by a colon displayed below

```
1 - Monday : 2 - Tuesday : 3 - Wednesday
```

I want it replace each colon with a newline character so it will look something like this:

```
1 - Monday <br />
2 - Tuesday <br />
3 - Wednesday
```

Please advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said - *replace* it.

```
with test (col) as
  (select '1 - Monday : 2 - Tuesday : 3 - Wednesday' from dual)
select replace(col, ':', '<br>') new_col
from test;
```

Go to `NEW_COL`'s attributes and set "Escape special characters" to "No".

---

Though, consider not to store such a values into the same item (column in a table, that is). Should have been 3 different rows spread through 2 different columns.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks! it worked for what i needed it to do. Many Thanks.